# Which is the smarter way to pass data between views if i'm using storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard

I've read about this topic and can't decide which option would be the best for me. I need to pass data to another view when the user taps a button in a `UITableViewCell`.

As i read, the first part is the same for every option. I create a property in `ViewController2.h`, and then import `ViewController2.h` to `ViewController1.h`.

After these steps i have to choose an option to pass the data:

**1. option -** Using segues
In this case i need to drag the segue from the `UIButton` that placed in the `SampleCustomTableViewCell` or i have to select the ViewController1 and drag the segue from there?

**2. option -** Put something like this:

```
ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
viewController2.myArray = self.someValue;
[self pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

into the method that i call when the button pressed in the cell?

So i would like to know that which option is the better and why? I think specifically to the most important pros and contras (if they have). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using storyboards (and you generally should be), the best way to transition between view controllers is with segues.

And if you're using segues (which you should be if you're using storyboards), the best way to transfer data between view controllers is by implementing `UIViewController`'s `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueID"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[MyVC class]]) {
            MyVC *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
            dest.myArray = self.someValue;
        }
    }
}
```

You can drag a segue directly from a button to a destination and the segue will happen automatically.  But personally, I prefer dragging ALL of my segues from one view controller to the other and calling the segue manually.  Even if that sometimes means there's an `IBAction` method with nothing but the segue call.

Even if the segue is dragged directly from a button and called automatically, your first view controller will still call the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Great! It was a little bit confusing before your explanation. First the not segue option was more likeable for me, but now i understand why the segues are more useful. Thank you!

Comment: At first, it's unclear why the two `if` checks are in the `prepareForSegue` method, but this method will handle every segue from this view controller.  And nothing prevents two segues from having the same identifier but different destination classes... so we need some verification to prevent crashing.  And with 10 different segues, this can get a bit complicated... but at the end of the day, a single complicated method that handles ALL of the navigation logic for your view controller is preferable from having `pushViewController:animated:` methods scatter everywhere.